# Is there a way to get an alert when a file has been dropped in a specific directory?

Tags: vsftpd

Running vsftpd on Ubuntu Focal 20.04.3LTS.  Is there a way to get a pop-up alert if someone drops a file into my /incoming folder?

Comment: Read `man -k inotify`. `inotifywatch` and `grep --line-buffered` will help.

Comment: It might.  Let me see what I can do with this information.  Thanks.